# Flutter :- Inside the PageView Image is not setting to fit the screen on width?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am using the `PageView` for the view-pager functionality and showing the image on each page with contains some text and button on each page.
As I am using the `Stack` widget for putting the view on one another like `Relative-layout` in `Android`,  But My Image on the First Page of the `PageView` is not set to fit on the screen
I have tried the below solution like below
  [1).First link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716067/show-fullscreen-image-at-flutter) 
  [2). Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745448/how-do-i-stretch-an-image-to-fit-the-whole-background-100-height-x-100-width)  
But not getting the proper solution, I have tried the below lines of code for it,

```
class MyTutorialScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Material(
      child: PageIndicatorContainer(
        pageView: PageView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
      //////ON THIS SECTION I AM GETTIG PROBLEM
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
      /////// NEED THE SOLUTION ON THIS SECTION 
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Image.asset('images/walkthrough_1.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
                ),
                Positioned(
                    top: 40.0,
                    right: 40.0,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        print("HERE IS I AM");
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "SKIP",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    )),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 48.0,
                  left: 10.0,
                  right: 10.0,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Welcome",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Text(
                            "To The Ravindra Kushwaha App. \n One tap Club Destination !",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Image.asset('images/walkthrough_2.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              child: Image.asset('images/walkthrough_3.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
            )
          ],
        ),
        length: 3,
        align: IndicatorAlign.bottom,
        indicatorSpace: 5.0,
        indicatorColor: Colors.white,
        indicatorSelectorColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And please check the screen which I am getting from the above code [image]

Above the screen, how would I remove the white color on the right side?

I am using this library for the indicator

> **page_indicator: ^0.2.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below line to show image as per device width and height..Try below lines of code and let me know in case of concern

```
 Container(
    height: double.maxFinite, //// USE THIS FOR THE MATCH WIDTH AND HEIGHT
    width: double.maxFinite,
    child:
    Image.asset('images/walkthrough_3.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it worked `double.maxFinite`

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the `ViewPager` (**`PageView`**) functionality , by below lines of code, I am posting the answer for the other which can be helpful for the future user.

I have used this library for the indicator like below

> **page_indicator: ^0.2.1**

Please check the below lines of code for it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:page_indicator/page_indicator.dart';

class MyTutorialScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Material(
      child: PageIndicatorContainer(
        pageView: PageView(
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),

          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: double.maxFinite,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  child:
                      Image.asset('images/walkthrough_1.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),
                ),
                Positioned(
                    top: 40.0,
                    right: 40.0,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        print("HERE IS I AM");
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "SKIP",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    )),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 48.0,
                  left: 10.0,
                  right: 10.0,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Welcome",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Text(
                            "To The Ravindra Kushwaha App. \n One tap Club Destination !",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: double.maxFinite,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  child:
                      Image.asset('images/walkthrough_2.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),
                ),
                Positioned(
                    top: 40.0,
                    right: 40.0,
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        print("HERE IS I AM");
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "SKIP",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    )),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 48.0,
                  left: 10.0,
                  right: 10.0,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Welcome",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Text(
                            "To The Ravindra Kushwaha App. \n One tap Club Destination !",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: double.maxFinite,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  child:
                      Image.asset('images/walkthrough_3.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 48.0,
                  left: 10.0,
                  right: 10.0,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Welcome",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                            "To The Ravindra Kushwaha App. \n One tap Club Destination !",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),

                        child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Let's GO!!"),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
        length: 3,
        align: IndicatorAlign.bottom,
        indicatorSpace: 5.0,
        indicatorColor: Colors.white,
        indicatorSelectorColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```